# Dashes not allowed in virtual host entry?

Tags: apache, apache2

Strange error.  Was trying to figure out why a virtual host was not working using a setup I've used a hundred times.

```
    DocumentRoot "/var/htdocs/directory-name/"
    <Directory "/var/htdocs/directory-name/">
```

Gave me a 403 error no matter what I tried

```
    DocumentRoot "/var/htdocs/directoryname/"
    <Directory "/var/htdocs/directoryname/">
```

Did not.  Has anyone else ever experienced this?  I didn't paste the entire virtual host entry, but this was the only difference between what worked and what gave me a 403.  I'm totally bewildered.

Comment: I think in this case, seeing the actual path would be helpful or even necessary

Comment: I'm seeing this and it's driving me insane.  The issue for me is with a ServerName having a hyphen in it www.our-site.com

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you have a physical folder "directory-name" at "/var/htdocs". Could be some unrelated problem otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to add an entry like

```
127.0.0.1        test.directory-name.com
```

in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` ? (if using a test environment on Windows)

Also, double-check any `.htaccess` files you have for unwanted Rewrites / redirects